# Looking up templated type in gdb's Python

Tags: c++, gdb-python

I've loaded up two versions of a C++ library in gdb, opened up the built-in Python interpreter, and run

```py
import gdb
gdb.lookup_type('Foo<Bar>')
```

In one version, it works just fine.  However, in the other, I get

```
gdb.error: No type named Foo<Bar>.
```

I've confirmed that both the `Foo` template as well as the `Bar` class still exist in the latter library's source.  What could explain the failure to look up the type?  Does `Foo<Bar>` have to "exist" in the source in that combination for the type to show up under gdb?

Running `file` on the libraries produces

```
libfoo.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildId[xxHash]=..., with debug_info, not stripped
```

Comment: Yes, the program needs to have an instantiation of `Foo<Bar>` somewhere.  `gdb` is not a C++ compiler, it will not instantiate templates for you.

Comment: So, would I use `nm` to see what types are exported?

Comment: I don't think `nm` can show this. Try `objdump --dwarf=info` instead.

Comment: Do you know what in the `objdump` output would indicate that `gdb.lookup_type` will succeed?  I see several things like `Foo<Baz>` which show up but still fail under `lookup_type`.